# Urllib2 in python: why is it not returning the webpage formatting and not the actual data

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, urllib2

can someone tell me why, when I run this code:

```
import urllib2
for i in range(1,2):
        id_name ='AP' + str("{:05d}".format(i))
        web_page = "http://aps.unmc.edu/AP/database/query_output.php?ID=" + id_name
        page = urllib2.urlopen(web_page)
        html = page.read()
        print html
```

It returns:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>detailed information</title>
<style type="text/css">
H1 {font-family:"Time New Roman", Times; font-style:bold; font-size:18pt; color:blue}
H1{text-align:center}
P{font-family:"Time New Roman", Times; font-style:bold; font-size:14pt; line-height:20pt}
P{text-align:justify;margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px;color:blue}
/body{background-image:url('sky.gif')}
/
A:link{color:blue}
A:visited{color:#996666}
</style>
</head>
<H1>Antimicrobial Peptide APAP00001</H1>
<html>
<p style="margin-left: 400px; margin-top: 4; margin-bottom: 0; line-height:100%">
<b>
<a href = "#" onclick = "window.close(self)"><font size="3" color=blue>Close this window
</font> </a>
</b>
</p>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

And not the actual data on the page (http://aps.unmc.edu/AP/database/query_output.php?ID=00001) (e.g. net charge, length)?

If I edit this code slightly somehow, is it possible to return all of the information on the page (e.g. the information about net charge, length etc), and not just information about how the page is formatted?

Thanks

Edit 1: Due to Gahan's comment below, I tried this:
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

```
for i in range(8,9):
        webpage = "https://dbaasp.org/peptide-card?type=39&id=" + str(i)
        response = requests.get(webpage)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
        print soup
```

However, I still seem the same answer (for example, if I run the edit 1 code and direct output to a file, and then grep the peptide sequence in the output file, it is not there).

Comment: why did you changed url in second place?

Answer (score 2):

In your original snippet, you use "AP00001" as query param:

```
id_name ='AP' + str("{:05d}".format(i))
```

so your url is: "http://aps.unmc.edu/AP/database/query_output.php?ID=AP00001", instead of "http://aps.unmc.edu/AP/database/query_output.php?ID=00001"

A fixed version of your first snippet using `requests`:

```
url = "http://aps.unmc.edu/AP/database/query_output.php"
for i in range(1,2):
    id_name = "{:05d}".format(i)
    response = requests.get(url, params={"ID":id_name})
    print response.content
```

Comment: This was so helpful, thank you so much for your time.

Answer (score -1):

use requests library:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
data_require = ["Net charge", ]
for i in range(1,2):
    id_value ="{:05d}".format(i)
    url = "http://aps.unmc.edu/AP/database/query_output.php"
    payload = {"ID": id_value}
    response = requests.get(url, params=payload)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
    table_structure = soup.find('table')
    all_p_tag = table_structure.find_all('p')
    data = {}
    for i in range(0, len(all_p_tag), 2):
        data[all_p_tag[i].text] = all_p_tag[i+1].text.encode('utf-8').strip()
        print("{} {}".format(all_p_tag[i].text, all_p_tag[i+1].text.encode('utf-8').strip()))
    print(data)
```

Note:
you don't need to convert `"{:05d}".format(i)` to string as it will only return string when you use `format()` because it's string formatting.

also I have updated code to get tag details too.
you don't need to use grep for it because BeautifulSoup is already providing such facility.

Comment: I appreciate the help but that did not work for me. I changed the code as described (I added the code to the question above), however, as I describe above, I still don't see the required information (e.g. when I grep the peptide sequence in output file from the suggested code, the peptide sequence is not there?). Thank you for the help though, i appreciate it.

Comment: While using `requests` instead of urllib2 is certainly a good advice (in that it makes life easier), it won't by itself solve the problem of passing a wrong 'id' param. Also, if using `requests`, at least learn to use it properly (passing the query params as a dict instead of manually building the querystring: `requests.get("http://aps.unmc.edu/AP/database/query_output.php", params={"ID":"00001"})`

Comment: if there is not multiple parameters and request method is GET I don't mind to build it manually, because if parameters exist then it will be also processed through same stage, and at last they will be concatenated.

Comment: @E.Dohrty and @brunodesthuilliers; check for code update